# Headers to set for AJAX calls in a custom webserver

Tags: ajax, http, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, webserver

I'm writing a custom web server. When I enter the URL of my server in the browser, I get the sample text I write out to the socket in my browser correctly. This is the HTTP response that I write:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Server: My Server\r\n
Date: Blah\r\n
Content-Type: text/plain\r\n
\r\n
This is some sample text. This appears in my browser correctly when I connect directly to the server entering the URL.
```

However, if I use Ajax (jQuery) to access the same URL and then set the innerHTML of an element on the HTML page, I do not get any data printed. Is there any other header I need to set on my web server so that the browser's XMLHttpRequest object detects the response?

Comment: Thank you for the link, @S.Mark : https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control#Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Used firebug to look at the actual headers in this example: http://arunranga.com/examples/access-control/preflightInvocation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably needed `Content-Type`

Comment: I tried setting Content-Type: text/plain 
It still doesn't work.

Comment: @ErJab, Is that cross-domain?

Comment: and Please use firebug to check headers, its properly getting or not.

Comment: Yes it is cross-domain, but I take care of it by processing the OPTIONS request sent by the browser. In Firebug, I see the browser first making the OPTIONS request since it is cross-domain and then it makes the GET request. When I examine the response headers, all the headers are set correctly, but the content alone is missing.

Comment: Just for the note about crosss-domain, its not allowed by default, you need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` , and more info at here https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control#Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Yes yes, I already did that! :) Even after that it doesn't work!

Comment: Imm, I see. Is your site online, btw?

Comment: @S.Mark Thank you so much for the link! It's working now! I saw an example HTTP exchange. So when a cross-domain AJAX request is made, first an OPTIONS header is made. In this I set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * and Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS. And after that, the actual POST request is triggered. It turns out I need to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header once again in this POST response for it to work! 
And I was testing it on two servers on my LAN.
Thanks again!